# Strange Segmentation fault using std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

Have a look at this snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
  string foo;
  base() {};
  base(const base &orig) {
    this->foo = orig.foo;
  };
 ~base() {} ;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  string bar;
  derived(const derived &orig) : base(orig) {
    this->bar = orig.bar;
  }
  derived() : base() {} ;
  ~derived() {};
};

void asd(derived d)
{
    // works fine
    cout << d.foo << d.bar << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<derived> v;

    derived bla;

    bla.foo = "Test ";
    bla.bar = "String ";

    v.push_back(bla);

    asd(bla);

    // Why the hell does v.end()->foo and v.end()->bar segfault?!
    cout << v.end()->foo;
    cout << v.end()->bar << endl;
}
```

Why do I get an segmentation fault? This is the console output
(compiled with g++ -o test test.cpp -g)

```
./test
Test String 
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test
```

The this pointer of the class derived v.end() does not point to the correct position...
But why?

Comment: it's incorrect to access by `v.end()` iterator. This iterator is  always invalid.

Comment: Also remember to make your base class destructor virtual.

Comment: When a segmentation fault is easy to repeat, you can generally find out the exact location of it by running in the debugger. As to being "strange", it's not strange unless it's not caused by trying to access memory you're not permitted to access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`end()` is not an iterator pointing to the last element.  It points to one past the last element.  Dereferencing `end()` is illegal.

Use [`back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) if you want the last element.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, `rbegin()` may also be appropriate.

Comment: Oh damn, you are right.... I forgot it. This costed me two days :-( Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

your problem is the use of v.end().

quoted from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/)

Return iterator to end
Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container.

The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the vector. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.

Because the ranges used by functions of the standard library do not include the element pointed by their closing iterator, this function is often used in combination with vector::begin to specify a range including all the elements in the container.

If the container is empty, this function returns the same as vector::begin.

use v[0] instead. (for this specific test, see other suggestions for vector getters in the quoted page).